# how to write an xml schema that allows part of the sequence not in place

Tags: xml, xsd

I need to write an XML schema that accept XMLs such as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data>
  <NodeA>something</NodeA>
  <NodeB>something</NodeB>
  <NodeC>something</NodeC>
  <NodeD>something</NodeD>
</Data>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data>
  <NodeA>something</NodeA>
  <NodeC>something</NodeC>
  <NodeB>something</NodeB>
  <NodeD>something</NodeD>
</Data>
```

So in general, I want the elements in the list to be sequenced, except that a part of the list can appear in any order.

However I tried several appoaches for the xsd file and none of them works, e.g.

```
<xs:complexType name="Data">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="NodeA"/>
    <xs:all xmlns:xs="">
      <xs:element name="NodeB"/>
      <xs:element name="NodeC"/>
    </xs:all>
    <xs:element name="NodeD"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Putting NodeB and NodeC in a group doesn't work either.

I've googled those error messages but couldn't find anything useful...Why these xsds fails and how should I write it? Thanks!

Comment: find some other threads with different problems but caused by same issue. seems like it's a shortcoming of XML schema
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/839079/middle-way-between-xsd-all-and-xsd-sequence
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408095/xml-schema-putting-both-sequence-and-all-under-one-complextype-node
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420512/how-to-mix-xsdsequence-with-xsdall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="NodeA"/>
                <xs:choice>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="NodeB"/>
                        <xs:element name="NodeC"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="NodeC"/>
                        <xs:element name="NodeB"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:choice>
                <xs:element name="NodeD"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thanks! However I also tried this one before and the editor also throws an error...  And a problem with this one is that the number of choices will increase in combination speed, so if I have more nodes I will be in trouble

Comment: xs:choice is the correct way. Try <xs:element name="Data"><xs:complexType><xs:sequence...... If this is not working there must be something wrong with the XSD as I tried it in oxygenxml and it worked no problem. If you need more help you'll have to post the entire XSD so that it can be verified to be well formed. Can't help any more I'm afraid (work to do)